# How to get GDAL >= 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, r, gis

I have some software programmed in R using [`sf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html), which require GDAL version >= 2.0.0.

But Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS has only [1.11.3+dfsg-3build2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=libgdal-dev).

How can I get GDAL version >= 2.0.0 on 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

sudo apt-get update
```

and install packages from it:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

As `ppa:nextgis/dev` caused me a some trouble when installing `sp package` [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/884#issuecomment-435916734) and seem to also cause [there](https://github.com/ropensci/MODIStsp/issues/155)

> DISCLAMER: I'm not running pure Ubuntu, but Linux Mint which is **based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Comment: Awesome Man! You saved my day!